# how to delete many documents from a collection based on a condition with values from an other collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

here is attached the aggregate query 
i want to delete all the returning values of this query from the same collection "History"
how to do it ?

[image]

lets say i have a collection of stock-market companies records named "history" as

```
{_id:"value",symbol:"value",date:"value",open:"value",close:"value",......}
```

my file is supposed to have a document for each company for each day , in total 42days  of records for each company 
but after checking the data it seems like some companies doesn't have all the 42days records "one document/day" they have less 
so i want to delete the companies who doesn't have exactly 42 documents 
my group by will be on the "symbol" my count on "date"  i can get the list but i don't know how to delete it

Comment: Please edit this question with data in text format rather than images !! Also what do you mean by *values from an other collection* Please give us sample docs, input & required o/p..

Answer (score 1):

You can remove them running `.remove` method.

```
db.history.aggregate(...).forEach(function(doc){
    db.history.remove({symbol: doc._id});
})
```

**Note:** It's very slow.

**Alternative solution:** Change aggregation criteria to return valid documents and override `history` collection with [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) operator:

```
db.history.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$symbol",
      nbr_jours: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      nbr_jours: {
        $gte: 42 //$eq
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "history"
  }
])
```

**Note:** It's very fast.

Comment: thank you, the first one works , time is less than 40sec no pb for the Alternative solution i need to practice more i can't figured it out now